# Trying to build an Android Launcher - "Home" doesn't work on Pixel 5 api31

Tags: android, manifest, launcher

I'm trying to build a simple launcher for Android.
I started with some code samples from different sources (last one is [that](https://steemit.com/utopian-io/@ideba/how-to-build-a-custom-android-launcher-and-home-screen-application-part-1) one)

I'm doing the first steps, creating a project with an empty Activity and changing the "AndroidManifest.xml" so it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.FiftyLauncher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I see that it works on some emulators (pixel 3,4) but it doesn't work on pixel 5 api 31 .
(Works = pressing the home button will show me the option to use my launcher.
Doesn't work = pressing home just opens the default launcher)

Any idea what am I missing?
Thank you,
Saar.

Comment: Is your app set as the default launcher app? Check in the settings of the device where it doesn't work if your app is set as the launcher. On my phone the setting is called "Default home app".

Comment: Thank you. I'm not looking for a default yet, only to be asked weather to use my launcher or the default one...